# How use requirements for variable in symfony route

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I need to add a requirement for my api route (only allow 3 mgn , user and adm) but i get the error:

MissingMandatoryParametersException

Some mandatory parameters are missing ("role") to generate a URL for route "api_doc".

here is my route:

```
api_platform:
   resource: .
   type: api_platform
   prefix: /{role}/api
   requirements:
        role: "mng|adm|user"
```

should i install or set something?, thank you

Comment: Please provide more details. What is the full stack trace? What does the code producing the error look like?

Comment: You're trying to change the base url of your api with a dynamic variable, so when API Platform tries to generate a route, it's missing the `role` variable and fails. I'm not sure what would be right way to handle this but maybe you could explain why you need to have a role variable in the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

already find a solution
if some person need it

```
api_platform:
   resource: .
   type: api_platform
   prefix: /{app}/api
   defaults:
       app: take|mngr|drvr
   requirements:
        app: take|mngr|drvr
```

thank you